# GTM Element Visibility trigger not firing

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to track an element that appears after I click a button with GTM, but using Element Visibility trigger doesn't fire at all. I had GTM setup for some clicks and it worked fine, but I'm stumped with this Visibility trigger. I tried toggling `Observe DOM changes` but that didn't work. I thought maybe my CSS Selector is wrong so I changed it to `body` but that didn't work too. Is there anything I'm missing here?

The following picture is the settings for tracking `body`. This should fire when the page is loaded because normally all contents are displayed in body.
[image: body configuration]

Comment: Is the minimum percent visible being reached?

Comment: @Ben It's quite a while ago but I remember also trying setting the percentage to 0 or 10 or something like that. That also didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Check item "Observe DOM changes" and time too (set 3000 or 1500 (test it) miliseconds)

Comment: I'm working on another part of the website, but if I happen to work on this part again, I'll give it a shot and post an update here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a . before the class, so instead of just body use .body

I was stuck with a custom class not working until I added the . before it, which then made it work.

Comment: .body is going to target a class that doesn't exist.